# Comparing future dates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I know this is probably a pretty simple question, but i am trying to write a function that returns a bool value of "true" if a date passed is in the future, like this:

```
bool IsFutureDate(System.DateTime refDate)
{
    if (refDate > DateTime.Now)  // This doesn't seem to work
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Anyone tell me who to write a function like this that actually works?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I think the emphasis here is on the "seem" word, as it should work. What dates are you checking? Can you give us a working example, a short but complete program, that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Also, you can shorten the entire body down to just: return refDate > DateTime.Now; and besides, unless you plan on adding more information, I'd just drop the whole method (after you've figured out why it doesn't seem to work that is), and just use the comparison instead.

Comment: Wow I feel so embarassed. I was under the impression that you could not use equality and compare operators on DateTime objects. I could have sworn I tried this code before and got a compile error. But it does work! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also note the answer by Nick regarding timezones.

Comment: `return refDate > DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is you might get undefined behaviour if refDate == today.

DateTime.Now includes the time. If refDate if for say today at 3:00 and you run it at 2:00 it will return true. If you run at 4:00 it will return false.

Compare it to DateTime.Today and that will just return the date, preventing the time of day influencing it.

Other than that it should all be fine..

Comment: Note that DateTime.Today has a time of 12 AM (00:00). Comparing a date that's sometime today against that will say it's in the future. If you want to check if the date portion is in the future, you could use: refDate.Date > DateTime.Today

Answer (score 3):

DateTime handling is always tricky.

I have summarized what's been mentioned so far and made this post Community Wiki.

### Time Zone Handling

```
static bool IsFutureDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
   // NOTE: ToUniversalTime() treats DateTimeKind.Unspecified as local time. We
   //       therefore insist that the input kind is always specified.
   if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
       string msg = "dateTime.Kind must not be DateTimeKind.Unspecified.";
       throw new ArgumentException(msg, "dateTime");
   }

   return dateTime.ToUniversalTime() > DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

### Comparing Dates Only

```
static bool IsFutureDate(DateTime date) {
    return date.Date > DateTime.Today;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsFutureDate(DateTime refDate) {
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    return (refDate.Date != today) && (refDate > today);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TimeSpan structure is helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

How precise do you need it to be?  Down to the millisecond?